# Beginner Assembly Language C - Subtracting to find what CPU added

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code, objdump

```
000000000040050f <oranges>:
...
40053f: 89 cf             mov %eax,%edi
400541: e8 a7 ff ff ff    callq 4004ed<apples>
400546: 0f af c3          imul %ebx, %eax
...
```

Oranges calls apples twice. Apples starts at 0x00000000004004ed. However, in the second call to apples in the machine code, the number in the function call is 0xFFFFFFA7

I need to figure out what number the CPU added with 0xFFFFFFA7 to get the address of apple() 0x00000000004004ed

Essentially, I need to do a subtraction problem. How do I subtract 0xFFFFFFA7 and 0x00000000004004ed in order to find what was added to the CPU? What is the right way to convert to make this make sense ?

Answer (score 2):

`call rel32` is relative to the *end* of the call instruction.

And the little-endian rel32 is a 2's complement integer, so `0xFFFFFFA7` it's a small negative number.   **`0xFFFFFFA7 - 2^32 = -89`** (decimal), i.e. jump 89 bytes backwards.

You correctly decoded the 4-byte little-endian  rel32 displacement into a binary integer, but didn't reinterpret it as signed 2's complement.  (It's not subtracted, it's added.  That's why it's negative).

`e8 a7 ff ff ff    callq rel32` ends at address `0x400546` (the start of the next instruction), so that will be RIP during its execution.  New RIP *after* executing it will be
**`0x400546 - 89 = 0x4004ed`**,  same as `objdump -d` printed.
objdump of course calculated that address the same way I did.

(Although objdump probably sign-extended the displacement to 64-bit before adding to a 64-bit code address.  Working out that bit-pattern 0xFFFFFFA7 means `-89` decimal as a 2's complement integer is basically like reading those 4 bytes into an `int32_t` and adding it to a `uint64_t`.  (Intel's manual for https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call also describes the process as sign-extending the rel32 for binary addition, but that's just another way to express the same math in a more machine-friendly way.  Other than the sign-extension, all of this works identically in any mode for direct relative `call` and `jmp` instructions.  `jmp rel8` uses an 8-bit 2's complement branch displacement.)

---

Semi-related: [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) has an example of manually encoding a `call` to a given target address.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance [and loosely] ...

You're using an x86 in 64 bit mode.

64 bit mode has a special addressing mode known as "RIP relative" addressing.

**Edit:** From Peter, the addressing mode is actually `call rel32`, rather than `RIP relative`, although the offset calculations will be the same.

The `%rip` register is the program counter. It changes on each instruction.

So, when using this mode, the offset is how far away the target address (e.g. `apples`) is from the address of the current instruction (from the address in `%rip` for the instruction).

Since you have *two* `callq` instructions (from your description, but *not* shown in the code), they each have a different address, so the offset to `apples` will be different.

This allows for "position independent code". It also allows an offset to be used, which is usually smaller than a full 64 bit absolute address. That's why the `callq` instruction (opcode + offset/address) is only 5 bytes (vs. 9 bytes) because the offset is a signed 32 bit quantity.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I thought rip may be involved. In this particular instance, can you help me decipher how to find the rip% or kind of walk through this specific problem?

You could do: `objdump --disassemble myprogram` to get a disassembly and look at the disassembly. Or, you could do this with the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) using the `disassemble` command.

From your listing, the address of the `callq` is 0x400541 and [you mentioned that] `apples` is at 0x4004ed.

So, the offset from the *start* of the `callq` instruction is:

```
-84 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFAC
```

But, the instruction has an offset of:

```
0xFFFFFFFA7
```

(Remember that the disassembly just puts out the bytes, so we have to manually reverse the bytes because the offset is little-endian).

So, this means that the `%rip` value used is *not* the *start* of the instruction, but, rather the *end* of the instruction.

So, we have to adjust the offset by the length of the instruction [which is 5] to get 0xFFFFFFA7. That is, the `%rip` value [used by] the `callq` instruction is the address of the instruction + 5. In pseudo code, the calculation is:

```
offset = apples - (&callq + 5)
```

Comment: I thought rip may be involved. In this particular instance, can you help me decipher how to find the rip% or kind of walk through this specific problem?

Comment: @craig: `call rel32` is not new for 64-bit mode; the E8 opcode dates back all the way to 8086 (where it was `call rel16` in 16-bit mode of course. [Why do x86 jump/call instructions use relative displacements instead of absolute destinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46184755)).  What's new in 64-bit mode is RIP-relative addressing for *data*, like `mov eax, [RIP + symbol]`.  (And also that call can't reach the entire address space, because immediates / displacements are still 32-bit, so yes it's sign-extended to 64-bit before adding to the address of the end of the call / jmp instruction)

Comment: PIC was possible in 32-bit code as well, with inconveniences only for data access.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, Peter. I put "loosely" at the top because I suspected you'd be around :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes So, from your comment [and answer] the instruction is actually `call rel32` rather than `RIP relative`? So, even if the offset calculations are the same, it's a misnomer to call it `RIP relative` here? If so, I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't use the phrase "RIP relative".  That's almost always used to refer to the ModRM *data* addressing mode that x86-64 added.  In a computer science class, if you wanted to talk about the "addressing mode" that branches use, you would say it's PC relative or RIP relative, but only if someone asked about that in the first place.  Relative branches are the norm in many ISAs, especially ones wider than 16-bit.  In x86 terms, given that memory-indirect branches like `call [rip + global_func_ptr]` are possible, we normally reserve "addressing mode" for *data* accesses.

Comment: `call rel32` is a handy way to unambiguously reference one of the encodings for that mnemonic as listed in the manual.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call.  You could also say `e8 call` to name it by opcode, or "direct near call" (because the only non-indirect near call is this one. In 16 and 32-bit mode there's a direct far call which takes an absolute `ptr16:32`, but there's no 64-bit form of it).  `call rel32` is useful by analogy with jumps: `jmp rel32` and `jmp rel8` both exist, and target calculation works identically to call rel32.  I don't know if Intel formally uses these name.

Comment: @PeterCordes An FYI ... S.I.W.O.T.I. You may want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773308/small-vs-identical-types-of-loop-variables-in-c-c-for-performance#64773308 to explain _why_ `int_fast32_t` or `int_fast16_t` generate the 64 bit variants (e.g. `add $1,%rax`) Or, at least comment and link to one of your existing answers that [IIRC] covers in detail why 64 bit is actually faster [with register renaming, etc.]

Comment: @CraigEstey: ugh, 64-bit isn't faster than 32-bit.  Only 16-bit is sometimes slower.  I have a half-finished answer on [Cpp uint32\_fast\_t resolves to uint64\_t but is slower for nearly all operations than a uint32\_t (x86\_64). Why does it resolve to uint64\_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63045795) that I should finish and post; for almost all use-cases, that was a bad choice on gcc/glibc's part.  Thanks for the link.