# Small vs. identical types of loop variables in C/C++ for performance

Tags: c++, c, loops, types, integer

Say I have a large nested loop of the form

```
long long i, j, k, i_end, j_end;
...
for (i = 0; i < i_end; i++) {
  j_bgn = get_j_bgn(i);
  for (j = j_bgn; j < j_end; j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

with some large `i_end` and `j_end`, say `i_end = j_end = 10000000000`. If I know that `j_bgn` is always small, perhaps even always either `0` or `1`, is it beneficial performance-wise to use a smaller type for this, like `signed char j_bgn`? Or does this come with a recurring cost due to implicit casting to `long long` each time we begin a new `j` loop?

I guess this has a pretty minor effect, but I would like to know the "proper"/pedantic way of doing this: Either 1) keep all loop variables of the same type (and use the smallest type that can cold the largest integer needed), or 2) choose the type of each loop variable independently to be as small as possible.

#### Edit

From the comments/answers I see I need to supply further information:

- I sometimes want and sometimes do not want to use these variables (e.g. `j`) for indexing. Why is this relevant (as long as I make sure to use types large enough to cover my available memory)?
- In my actual code I use something like `size_t` (or `ssize_t`) for e.g. `j`, `j_end`. On modern hardware this is 64 bit.

I take it that using types smaller than 32 bit is not worthwhile, but is it still perhaps beneficial to use a 32 bit type for `j_bgn` rather than also using a 64 bit type (as I really do need for `j` and `j_end`)?

Comment: What gain do you expect from using a smaller type?

Comment: A safe approach is to use the same type for your counter as the end value's type. It keeps the code clear and avoids simple mistakes that could render your comparison incorrect.

Comment: I wouldn't bother using types smaller than the natural `int`. It won't yield any performance improvement. Also it depends if your loop is using these variables for something else (such as indexing arrays - in this case `size_t` should be considered)

Comment: @EugeneSh. smaller than the "native" for the hardware may even cause some performance loss on some processors (cortex-M for example)

Comment: An `int` is supposed to represent the word size of the machine architecture (although these days, it's common to be half-word size:  32-bit on a 64-bit architecture), and has the as-good-or-better performance than the other data types.  A `short` or `char` won't be faster than an `int`.  If you are concern about performance, consider leveraging a fast minimum sized type, like [`std::int_fast32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: @Eljay Speaking of *common these days*; technically 32 bits is a double word in 64 bit x86. It's a hybrid of architecture that has instructions for multiple word widths named word, double word, quad word, octo word ... `int` could reasonably be any one of those but everyone reasonably chose the one that has fastest operations.

Comment: @eerorika • 32-bits is a double-word in 16-bit x86 architecture (like on a 8086 or 80286), but not in 64-bit x86 architecture, and is the origin of the 16-bit WORD in the Windows APIs popularized by Petzold and used in the MSDN documentation.  But it's an anachronism (and misnomer) for 32-bit or 64-bit architecture.

Comment: @Eljay As far as I can tell, Windows API just follows the nomenclature of the Intel manuals.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but concerning "implicit casting to `long long`", there is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. So  a cast is always explicit. The appropriate term here is "implicit conversion".

Comment: @eerorika • Possibly an influence, and similar (but different) nomenclature continued in Intel and AMD instruction sets.  An accident of history (and now legacy) would explain why the Windows API uses anachronistic (and misnomer) terms for the modern architectures, as well as the non-Intel platforms they support.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an actual use case for the "fast" datatypes defined in [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) for C++ or `<stdint.h>` for C.

You can use `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t`, `int_fast32_t`, or `int_fast64_t` or their unsigned pendants, to get the fastest integer type that is at least 8, 16, 32, or 64 bytes large.

I guess if you want to be really pedantic, you should pick these and let the compiler pick the fastest option.

Comment: No, For the loop you should use native size integers (if possible of course) https://godbolt.org/z/hqYsz1

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Looking at the docs of these types looks like the answer is correct in theory, but the compiler seem to not implement it properly..

Comment: @EugeneSh. No it does it the correct way. This type has to behave as n-bits one. And int8_t is the fastest one which behaves as 8 bit integer. Actually the idea behind those types is a mystery. For my this answer it is a "google search" answer without practical understanding of the topic.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland "This type has to behave as n-bits one. And int8_t is the fastest one which behaves as 8 bit integer." - The reference disagrees. It states _"fastest signed integer type with width of **at least** 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively"_ Care to explain why it should behave _exactly_ like an int type?

Comment: @churill cite me exactly as I wrote it. It has to behave exactly as the n bits integer. If you did not understand `n` means 8,16 .... same as in (u)int_fast`n`_t.   **NOT AS ANY INTEGER** as you wrote

Comment: @churill example why it has to behave exactly as `n` bits normal integer https://godbolt.org/z/491E87

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Sorry, I don't get it. This proofs that in practice  (with this compiler and this platform) they behave like the corresponding int types. The standard doesn't say they have to. Maybe give me some more insights, since I don't seem to have practical understanding of the matter. Maybe there's a difference between C++ and C standards?

Comment: Yes, that's the sad state that `uint_fast8_t` is equal to `unsigned char` in gcc (see `gcc -dM -E - -x c </dev/null | grep FAST8`). I would be totally happy if gcc would finally change that to native fast type with at least 8 bits, like it should. I believe that would be fine to make a bug request to gcc, that this type is not the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Many platforms require some additional operations if the integers are wider or smaller than the width of the registers.  (Most 64-bit platforms can handle 32-bit integers as efficiently as 64-bit, though.)

Example (with empty `asm` statements to stop the loops optimizing away):

```
void lfoo(long long int loops)
{
    for(long long int i = 0; i < loops; i++) asm("");
}

void foo(int loops)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++) asm("");
}

void bar(short int loops)
{
    for(short int i = 0; i < loops; i++) asm("");
}

void zoo(char loops)
{
    for(char i = 0; i < loops; i++) asm("");
}
```

and the resulting code for old 32-bit ARM Cortex processors, without ARMv6 sign-extension instructions which make `short` slightly less bad ([Godbolt compiler explorer, gcc8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/GnnG19) default options, `-O3` without `-march=` or `-mcpu=cortex-...`)

```
lfoo:
        cmp     r0, #1
        sbcs    r3, r1, #0
        bxlt    lr
        mov     r2, #0
        mov     r3, #0
.L3:
        adds    r2, r2, #1
        adc     r3, r3, #0        @@ long long takes 2 registers, obviously bad
        cmp     r1, r3
        cmpeq   r0, r2            @@ and also to compare
        bne     .L3
        bx      lr

foo:
        cmp     r0, #0
        bxle    lr                @ return if loops==0 (predicate condition)
        mov     r3, #0            @ i = 0
.L8:                              @ do {
        add     r3, r3, #1          @ i++  (32-bit)
        cmp     r0, r3             
        bne     .L8               @ } while(loops != i);
        bx      lr                @ return

bar:
        cmp     r0, #0
        bxle    lr
        mov     r2, #0
.L12:                            @ do {
        add     r2, r2, #1          @ i++ (32-bit)
        lsl     r3, r2, #16         @ i <<= 16
        asr     r3, r3, #16         @ i >>= 16  (sign extend i from 16 to 32)
        cmp     r0, r3
        bgt     .L12             @ }while(loops > i)
        bx      lr
                @@ gcc -mcpu=cortex-a15 for example uses
                @@  sxth    r2, r3

zoo:
        cmp     r0, #0
        bxeq    lr
        mov     r3, #0
.L16:
        add     r3, r3, #1
        and     r2, r3, #255     @ truncation to unsigned char is cheap
        cmp     r0, r2           @ but not free
        bhi     .L16
        bx      lr
```

As you can see the most efficient are 32 bits integers as they have the same size as processor registers (function `foo`).

Comment: I'm not trained in reading assembly. Are the `.LXY` below `foo`, `bar`, etc. part of the function just above? Otherwise it seems `foo`, `bar` and `zoo` are all the same, with only `lfoo` being more expensive.

Comment: @jmd_dk if you do not know the assembler how can you say that they are identical. those are called labels and they are part of the function. The most interesting part is below the labels

Comment: Well I can compare the texts character by character and see that they are identical perfectly well...

Comment: @jmd_dk: I commented to asm to show where bar and zoo are more expensive.  Yes, `.Lnum` auto-numbered labels are branch targets *inside* function; that's how loops are implemented.

Comment: Might be a good idea to point out that `size_t` will always be fairly reasonable for loop counters, e.g. 32-bit on 32-bit CPUs.  On x86-64 it's usually wider than you need for most loops, and costs a bit of extra code size for REX prefixes.  (And 64-bit `div` is significantly slower than 32-bit on Intel CPUs, so 32-bit int is a natural size.)